# OpenCL array offset calculation using a 2D kernel workgroups

Tags: multidimensional-array, gpu, opencl

I am getting a hard time calculating the correct array offset using 2D workgroups. I am calling my kernel with these parameters

```
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&a_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&b_mem_obj);
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&c_mem_obj);

// Initialize kernel work dimensions 
const size_t globalWorkSizeCalc[2] = { 32, 32 }; //rows and cols ie x and y
const size_t localWorkSizeCalc[2] =  { 4, 4 }; //rows and cols ie x and y
//Total WorkGroups = (32/4) * (32/4) = 64
//LocalWorkGroups = (4*4) * 64 = 1024

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSizeCalc, localWorkSizeCalc, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Inside the Kernel how to calculate to correct index offset for a simple array addition?

```
//use vectors for conciseness
int2 globalId = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));  // 0..31 x 0..31
int2 localId = (int2)(get_local_id(0), get_local_id(1)); //0..3 x 0..3
int2 groupId = (int2)(get_group_id(0), get_group_id(1)); //0..7 x 0..7
int2 globalSize = (int2)(get_global_size(0), get_global_size(1)); //32 x 32
int2 localSize = (int2)(get_local_size(0), get_local_size(1));  //4 x 4
int2 numberOfGrp = (int2)(get_num_groups(0), get_num_groups(1));  //8 x 8

int index = ???
C[index] = A[index] + B[index];
```

Running the same code with localworksize of 32X32 like below,

```
const size_t localWorkSizeCalc[2] =  { 32, 32 };
```

I successfully calculated the offset, but with 4X4 I have a problem.

```
int index = (localSize.x *  localId.y) + localId.x;
C[index] = A[index] + B[index];
```

**EDIT (solution): It seems it worked with the code below but I am wondering if I can use localId's and Groups to accomplish the same. Any recommendation?

```
int index = (globalId.y * globalSize.x) + globalId.x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ‘int index = (globalId.y * globalSize.x) + globalId.x;‘ you already found the solution. This is a simple 2D linear index.
You could also substitude ‘globalId.x‘ by ‘groupId.x * localSize.x + localID.x‘ (same for ‘y‘) and ‘globalSize.x‘ by ‘numberOfGrp.x * localSize.x‘ (global size must be a multiple of local size for this to work), but this offers no additional benefits in this case. ‘localId‘ becomes useful only if you use local memory.

Comment: Like this ? `int index  = (groupId.y * localSize.y + localID.y) * (numberOfGrp.x * localSize.x)  + (groupId.x * localSize.x + localID.x)`. Does not seem to work. Anyway, I am trying to understand the way they work Global Ids vs Local Ids and that's why I am experimenting with this.

Comment: Yes like that. Strange that it does not work... globalId.x counts from 0 to globalSize.x-1=31, localId.x counts from 0 to localSize-1=3 for each workgroup individually. Workgroup offset in terms of global index is groupId.x*localSize.x. In x-direction, globalId.x counts 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8...31 and localId.x counts 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1...3. groupId.x counts 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2...7.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow since I am away from the office right now, and I will let you know.

Comment: Hi, I had some syntax error problems like localID --> localId. I fixed them, and now it works. `int index = ((groupId.y * localSize.y + localId.y) * (numberOfGrp.x * localSize.x)) + (groupId.x * localSize.x + localId.x);` 

Can I ask you something about my kernel.cl privately?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but can I email you ?

Comment: Sure, write me a mail then.

Comment: Thank you !! I just emailed you to the moritz.xxxxx@uni-xxxxxxx.de

Comment: Dear Moritz I sent also to *.cl file to your email. . Thank you